# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen einer Sage und einer Legende?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

Ich habe bisher die Wörter Sage und Legende synonym verwendet. Es gibt zwar Dinge die ich so nenne, und andere Dinge, die ich wieder anders nenne (bspw. würde ich nie die Niebelungenlegende sagen), aber bisher war mir kein Unterschied bewusst. Nun wurde mir aber in einer Diskussion gesagt, dass es nur ähnlich ist, der Unterschied wurde mir allerdings nicht erklärt. Ebenfalls Wikipedia meint, dass Sagen und Legenden (genau wie Märchen) nur ähnlich sind.

> Eine Sage [...] ist, dem Märchen und der Legende ähnlich

Quelle: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sage

Comment: Was sagen denn die Wörterbücher?

Comment: Was ist mit Mythos?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: Habe in meinem einen Wörterbuch, was ich zur Verfügung hatte auch nichts besonderes gefunden

Comment: @Em1: Ja, das könnte man auch noch dazu fragen^^.

Comment: Mythen zeichnen sich durch Anwesenheit von Göttern aus. :)

Comment: @user1451340 wobei man die diversen Soap-Opera-Folgen mit Beteiligung griechischer Götter aber eher als Sagen denn als Mythen bezeichnet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nach meinem Verständnis ist der Hauptunterschied zwischen Sagen und Legenden, dass es bei einer Legende oft um eine einzelne Person und ihrer Handlungen geht. Dabei gibt’s natürlich solche und solche Legenden. Elvis ist eine Legende, wobei seine Existenz aber feststeht. Dann gibt es noch solche Legenden, wie man sie anspricht, wenn man sagt „Die Legende besagt, dass …“, wobei das oft für mich so klingt, als wolle man einem Märchen etwas mehr Wahrheitscharakter geben. Und das ist meiner Meinung nach der Punkt; in Legenden steckt ein Kern Wahrheit, wobei die beeindruckende Leistung des Helden so unglaublich ist, dass man ihm problemlos auch noch einige unrealistischen Heldentaten hinzudichten kann. Doch der Kern Wahrheit bleibt.

Sagen hingegen drehen sich meist nicht um eine Person, sondern beziehen sich auf bestimmte Orte und deren Entstehungsgeschichte. Diese Geschichten sind (glaube ich ;) ) oft erfunden, machen die Entstehungsgeschichte jedoch etwas interessanter. Der Funken Wahrheit fehlt hier oft, mit Ausnahme der Existenz eines Ortes/geographischer Auffälligkeit/Person und nicht immer gibt es einen Helden. Diese Orte oder geographischen Auffälligkeiten existieren meist immer noch, weswegen die zugehörige Sage meist überhaupt weiter besteht, und die Entstehungsgeschichte „dokumentiert“. Die tatsächliche Existenz gibt hierbei der Sage noch etwas mehr Wahrheitscharakter. (Mir fällt da z. B. eine Sage ein, die zu einer alten Eiche gehört, die sehr merkwürdig verbogene Äste hat, was Kobolden, die jede Nacht dort sitzen, zuzuschreiben sei. Die Existenz der Eiche ist der „Beweis“, dass diese Sage wahr ist). Legenden bestehen oft auch lange über die Existenz dieser bestätigenden „Artefakte“ hinaus.

Ein weiterer Unterschied, den mir auch Wikipedia bestätigt hat, ist die Übertragungsweise von Sagen und Legenden. Legenden wurden häufig niedergeschrieben, Sagen hingegen werden mündlich weitergegeben.
Das spiegelt sich irgendwie auch heute noch wider; ich kenne einige Sagen, die ich über Google nicht finden kann, für Legenden reicht meist ein einziger Suchbegriff. Sagen werden mündlich weitererzählt, auch heute noch, und sind daher, mit einigen Ausnahmen, eher lokal bekannt. Legenden hingegen werden weiter verbreitet, auch wenn dies natürlich nicht auf alle „Die Legende besagt …“-Legenden zutrifft.

Comment: Wenn das im letzten Abschnitt beschriebene stimmt, bin ich jetzt auf die Wortherkunft von "Sage" gespannt ;)

Comment: Willst du im letzten Satz des zweiten Abschnittes eignetlich "Sagen" sagen? Wäre zumindest dem Kontext entsprechend passender.

Comment: Meinst du "Legenden bestehen oft auch lange über die Existenz dieser bestätigenden "Artefakte" hinaus."? Das meinte ich schon so. Die Eichen-Sage gäbe es wahrscheinlich ohne die Eiche heute nicht mehr, wohin eine Legende auch ohne solche greifbaren "Beweise" auskommt.

Comment: Dass Legenden niedergeschrieben werden (und dann gelesen werden müssen), verrät einem übrigens auch das Latinum. Die Nibelungensage gibt es zwar in Schriftform, aber natürlich reimt sich's, damit man man dem ursprünglichen Zweck der mündlichen Weitergabe leichter nachkommen kann (und, huch, die fängt mit "Uns ist in alten Mären ..." an, womit sie sich ihrerseits auf mündliche (Vor)überlieferungen stützt)

Answer (score 11):

Eine **Legende** ist eine nach heutigem Verständnis fantastische Erzählung über eine historische, d.h. real existierende Person. Typische Beispiele sind Heiligenlegenden, in denen die Wundertaten der Heiligen erzählt werden.

Demgegenüber sind **Sagen** Erzählungen über erfundene, zumeist fantastische Ereignisse, an real existierenden Orten. Beispiele sind Gründungssagen von Städten.

Im Unterschied zu Sage und Legende sind **Märchen** nicht an eine reale Person oder einen realen Ort gebunden. Märchen erzählen in der Regel moralische Geschichten über alltägliche Zusammenhänge (Haushalt, Beruf, Familie). Ihre Protagonisten sind keine Individuen sondern Platzhalter für alle Mitglieder des Publikums ("Jedermann").

Und während Sage und Legende sich auf einzelne Personen und Orte beziehen, erklärt der **Mythos** das Selbstverständnis eines ganzen Volkes. Beispiele sind Weltschöpfungsmythen.

Kurz:

**Legende**

- fantastische Taten oder Erlebnisse
- einer historischen Person

**Sage**

- fantastische Ereignisse
- an einem realen Ort

**Märchen**

- fantastische Ereignisse von exemplarischem Charakter ("Moral der Geschichte")
- erfundene "Jedermann"-Figuren

**Mythos**

- fantastische Ereignisse
- die das Selbstverständnis eines Volkes begründen

Answer (score 5):

Als Begriff der Literatur ist eine **Legende** eine Heiligengeschichte, gehört also dem religiösen Bereich an. (vgl. auch [Legende auf Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legende)) Das Wort *Legende* kommt vom lateinischen Verb *legere – lesen* in der Gerundivform *legenda*.
Mein Metzler Literaturlexikon sagt:

> mittellateinisch *legenda*, Plural von *legendum* das zu Lesende; später auch als Singular gebraucht.

Also die Legende: zu lesende (Geschichte von einem christlichen Heiligen).

Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch, wird *Legende* oder *legendär* einfach für etwas sehr Bekanntes gebraucht. Siehe Beispiel *Elvis ist eine Legende* in der ersten Antwort.

Legende wird auch als Spezialbegriff in der Kartographie und der Numismatik gebraucht. Der Text mit Erklärungen der verschiedenen Zeichen, Farben, Linien auf Landkarten wird *Legende* genannt. In der Numismatik ist die Legende Text, der das Bild auf der Münze umschließt.

**Sagen** sind Geschichten von wunderlichen Begebenheiten, die fest mit einem bestimmten Ort verbunden sind.

Märchen, Legenden, Sagen haben alle Wundersames als wesentliches Inhaltselement, sind aber doch grundverschieden. Legenden handeln oft von einem christlichen Heiligen,
Sagen sind meistens Gruselgeschichten, die außerhalb eines oft sehr begrenzten geografischen Raumes meist nicht bekannt sind. Märchen dagegen, wie die aus *Tausendundeine Nacht*, die von Perrault oder die von den Brüdern Grimm gesammelten, sind heute weltweit bekannt und sind nicht nur eine platte Gruselgeschichte wie die meisten Sagen, sondern haben literarischen Reiz, lassen sich oft auch in psychologischer Hinsicht deuten oder sind manchmal auch Ausdruck verhüllter Lebensweisheiten.

Neben den Begriffen Märchen, Legende und Sage müsste man auch den Begriff  **Mythos**, Plural **Mythen**, erwähnen. In erster Linie versteht man darunter die Mythen der Griechen, Geschichten von Göttern und den Anfängen der Welt, frühe menschliche Versuche, die Welt und den Kosmos zu erklären.

Mythen gibt es aber nicht nur von den Griechen. Mehr oder weniger alle Völker haben sich Fragen zu den Anfängen der Welt, der Menschen und den Mächten, die das Schicksal der Menschen beeinflussen, gestellt, und haben ihre Sicht in anschaulichen Geschichten wiedergegeben.

Der merkwürdigste Mythos findet sich wohl in Terry Pratchetts Science-Fiction/Fantasy-Romanen. Bei ihm schwebt eine Schildkröte mit Elefanten auf dem Rücken durch den Kosmos. Das ist keine Erfindung von Pratchett, sondern ein Mythos aus Indien.

> Die Welt ruht auf den Rücken von vier Elefanten (Berilia, Tubul, Groß-T'Phon und Jerakeen), die wiederum auf dem Rücken der Sternen-Schildkröte Groß-A'Tuin stehen. (Quelle: [Scheibenwelt auf Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheibenwelt))

Die durch den Weltraum „schwimmende“ Schildkröte ist ein von der indischen Mythologie inspiriertes Weltbild.

Answer (score 4):

Wir nehmen dieses Thema gerade in der Schule durch. Also jeweils die Hauptmerkmale:

Sage:

- Historische Bezüge (wahrer Kern)
- Teilweise Aufhebung von Natur und Kausalgesetzen. Deutliche Trennung von dies- und jenseitiger Welt.
- Reale Schauplätze
- Mündlich überliefert
- Genaue Orts- und Zeitangaben (hoher Realitätsanspruch)
- Stoffe und Motive für die Sage werden mit landschaftlichen Eigentümlichkeiten und Anspielungen vermischt.
- Inhalt wird bestimmt von einem historischen Ereignis oder von Heldentaten
- Personen werden meist namentlich genannt, manchmal haben sie auch nur Bezeichnungen (z.B. der Rattenfänger, die Jungfrau)
- Ein Beispiel für eine Sage ist das Nibelungenlied

Und jetzt im Vergleich die Legende:

- Historische Bezüge mit **enger Beziehung zur literarischen Tradition**
- **Keine** Aufhebung von Natur- und Kausalgesetzen
- Reale Schauplätze
- Genaue Orts- und Zeitangaben
- Inhalt wird bestimmt **von der Biographie** (meist Todesumstände) einer historischen Person - meist Heilige
- Heute benutzt man diesen Begriff auch für Geschichten über berühmte Sport-, Musik- oder Filmstars.
- Personen werden **immer** namentlich genannt
- Beruht nicht auf der Verkündung einer Historischen Wahrheit, sondern auf der Verkündung einer Glaubenswahrheit
- Ein Beispiel für eine Legende ist die Legende Barbaras von Nikomedien (Märtyrin)

Comment: Lieber Besserwisser, willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Beachte, dass das hier kein Forum ist, sondern Fragen und Antworten. Im Übrigen legen wir viel Wert auf Freundlichkeit zwischeneinander. Deine Antwort kann in ihrer jetzigen Form erhitzte Gemüter hervorrufen – zum Beispiel lässt man sich nicht gerne in diesem Ton sagen, dass man keine Ahnung hat. Ich würde dir raten, deine Antwort ohne Bezüge zu bereits existierenden nochmal umzuformulieren. Dann könnte ich mir auch vorstellen, sie positiv zu bewerten. Vielen Dank =)

Comment: Ist die Geschichte der hl. 3 Könige keine Legende? Wenn man einem Stern folgt, dann läuft man doch im Laufe der Nacht in einem Halbkreis, weil sich die Erde unter den Sternen dreht. Das widerspricht schon den Naturgesetzen, dass der Stern über dem angebl. Geburtsort Jesus steht, oder?

Comment: Kritik an anderen Antworten bitte direkt bei diesen abgeben, nicht in der eigenen Antwort, oder im Chat. Für beides ist wohl ein wenig Reputation nötig, die erst verdient werden muss.

Comment: @userunknown Wenn du einem Stern im Sternbild kleiner Wagen folgst, läufst du schnurstraks geradeaus.

Comment: @harper: Du meinst, wenn man dem Polarstern folgt, dann läuft man schnurstracks nach Norden? Sollen denn die Weisen aus dem Morgenland aus dem heutigen Jordanien oder Saudi Arabien gekommen sein oder gar aus der unmittelbaren Nachbarschaft?

Comment: @userunknown Das sind gleich zwei Fragen. 1. Ja wenn du auf Sternen im Norden zuläufst, läufst du ... in den Norden. 2. Landesteile der genannten Länder sind südlich von Bethlehem. Allerdings hat sich wohl in dem Zeitraum eine Supernova ereignet, zu in der Legende Berücksichtigung gefunden haben könnte. Die Nova war wohl nicht direkt im Norden. Zumindest der Halbkreis ist aber widerlegt.

Comment: Nicht auf Sterne, sondern auf einen, den Nordstern. Nur kommt man dann nicht in Bethlehem zu stehen, sondern am Nordpol. Was heißt "hat sich wohl eine Supernova ereignet"? Wie kommst Du darauf? Kannst Du den Zeitraum näher eingrenzen - die Bibelgläubigen streiten ja noch, ob es war, als  Quirinius Statthalter von Syrien war, oder ob es in die Zeit des Königs Herodes fällt - nur eins kann stimmen, weil dazwischen mehr als 5 Jahre Differenz liegen. Und wie macht das so eine Supernova, über Bethlehem stehen zu bleiben und sich nicht am Nachthimmel weiterzudrehen? Nix ist widerlegt.

Comment: @userunknown Ich hatte lediglich widerlegt, dass das Laufen in Richtung eines Sterns zu einem halbkreis- förmigen Weg führen muss. Eine (Super-) Nova ist wohl ein zu kurzes Ereignis, dass muss ich einräumen. Eine Jupiter-Saturn-Konjuktion ist jedoch schon von Kepler für den Zeitraum berechnet worden. Interessante Hintergründe gibt's in der Mediathek des BR https://www.br.de/mediathek/video/sendungen/alpha-centauri/alpha-centauri-bethlehem-1999_x100.html

Comment: Du zitierst ernsthaft diesen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wop8xp_A4Ns Märchenonkelwissenschaftstheologen? Was sagt der denn zur Jupiter-Saturn-Konjunktion? Dass diese im Sternzeichen Fische 2 Monate im Westen von Bagdad zu sehen war, bis die hl. 3 Könige (sic!) in Jerusalem plötzlich nach Süden abbiegen, weil sie jetzt im Süden stehen? Das beantwortet doch meine Einwände überhaupt nicht! Hast Du das überhaupt geguckt?

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt wissenschaftliche Begriffsbestimmungen für Sage und Legende und es gibt den umgangssprachlichen Gebrauch, der zur Vermischung dieser Bedeutungen neigt. Der Schweizer Märchenforscher Max Lüthi charakterisierte in seinem Standardwerk "Das europäische Volksmärchen"(1) diese Erzählformen folgendermaßen:

> "Die ***Sage*** berichtet das Außerordentliche, Seltsame, Unerhörte;
>   sie lässt sich ergreifen vom einzelnen Geschehnis, sie erlebt und
>   sieht es als etwas Bedeutendes und stellt es als solches dar; sie
>   versucht Zusammenhänge aufzuzeigen, gibt aber keine endgültigen
>   Antworten wie die ***Legende***, welche das einzelne Geschehnis
>   eindeutig in einen dogmatischen Zusammenhang einordnet. (S. 77). Die
>   ***Sage*** ...glaubt ursprünglich an die Wirklichkeit des Erzählten, sie ist Wissenschaft und Dichtung in einem. ... Sie sieht den Menschen wie
>   den Jenseitigen vor allem als den Preisgegebenen, den Gequälten oder
>   Quälenden, den Frevler oder den Genarrten. ... Die ***Legende*** hingegen
>   gibt allen Dingen ihren Sinn. Sie bezieht sie alle auf ein und
>   denselben Mittelpunkt, auf Gott. Die ***Sage*** verwirrt, belustigt,
>   ängstigt, erregt den Menschen, die Legende klärt und festigt. Die
>   ***Sage*** stellt Fragen, die ***Legende*** gibt Antworten." (S. 78)

Das *Märchen* wird, obwohl es von seiner Struktur und Absicht her niemals vorgibt, eine unmittelbare Realität wiederzugeben, auch als Synonym für "Lüge" gebraucht: *Erzähl mir doch keine Märchen!* Als *Legende* werden auch Personen bezeichnet, die für die Menschen durch ihre Leistungen und ihre Persönlichkeit schon lange präsent sind und es nach ihrem Tod bleiben – mittlerweile wird stattdessen auch oft das Wort *Ikone* gebraucht. Das Nibelungenlied ist eine Heldendichtung und hat weder inhaltlich noch formal etwas mit einer Volkssage zu tun.

Die aktuelle Verwechslung von *Sage* und *Legende* wurde wahrscheinlich durch die Einführung des englischen Begriffs *Urban Legend* begünstigt, der auch immer wieder mit "urbane/städtische Legende" übersetzt wird (selbst der [Wikipedia-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderne_Sage), der diese Übersetzung als "ungeeignet" bezeichnet, verwendet sie wenige Absätze später trotzdem). An Lüthis Definition ist aber leicht zu erkennen, dass auch die "moderne, städtische Sage" denselben Mustern folgt wie die historischen Sagen.

(1) Max Lüthi: Das europäische Volksmärchen. Form und Wesen. (UTB 312). Bern: Francke (7) 1981, 1. Aufl. 1947

Answer (score -3):

> Der merkwürdigste Mythos findet sich wohl in Terry Pratchetts Science Fiction/Fantasy Romanen. Bei ihm schwebt eine Schildkröte mit einem Elefanten auf dem Rücken durch den Kosmos (erinnere mich nicht mehr so ganz genau an sein Bild). Das ist keine Erfindung von Pratchett, sondern ein Mythos aus Indien. Auch hier erinnere ich mich nicht mehr an genauere Details.

Auf [Groß A'Tuins](http://www.thediscworld.de/index.php/Gro%C3%9F_A'Tuin) rücken stehen vier Elefanten.

Ich denke der Wahrheitsgehalt spielt eine Rolle. Legendäre Taten sind doch mal allgemein gesagt "tolle" Dinge, die wirklich von Lebenden (oder auch Toten) vollbracht wurden.

Nach dem Motto "Wenn ich nicht die ganzen Platten von ihm schon gehört hätte würde ich nicht glauben das jemand so bekannt ist"  (auf Elvis bezogen)

Ich weiß auch, dass ich schon Sagen gelesen habe die nicht in dieser Region spielen.

Comment: Danke für die Richtigstellung mit den vier Elefanten.

Comment: Falls die Antwort von rogermue gelöscht wird, ist ein großer Teil dieser Antwort gegenstandslos. Antworten sollten auf eigenen Beinen stehen können ;)